# Nunit assert AreEqual dif because quotes

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, c#-3.0

I´m writing automation test for Api Rest.

In the body response to return:

```
"New Current Account"
```

I do the follow validation:

```
Assert.AreEqual("New Current Account", response.Content);
```

But it doesn´t work the Nunit return failed beacuse:

```
Message: 
      Expected string length 19 but was 21. Strings differ at index 0.
      Expected: "New Current Account"
      But was:  ""New Current Account""
      -----------^
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the string being returned actually contains quotes.

The proper way to reference this is by escaping the quotes that are part of the data in the string you use for an expected value.

Assert.AreEqual("\"New Current Account\"", response.Content);

This is preferable to using logic to trim off the quotes, because you are comparing actual to expected data without modifying either.

Comment: Yes, I resolved with this Assert.AreEqual("New Current Account", response.Content.Trim('"'));

Answer (score 1):

I resolved with follow alternative.

```
Assert.AreEqual("New Current Account", response.Content.Trim('"'));
```